# Can we merge tags 'rectangle' and 'rectangles'?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have both of these tags: [rectangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangles) and [rectangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangle).

Could we merge `rectangles` into `rectangle`?

Comment: And I'm not even talking about the relevance of that tag :P

Comment: Looking at a few of the questions under each tag, I'm not seeing any consistency to tell *what* the tags are even used for. Can you even be "an expert on rectangles"? I have to ask if we *need* the tags, to begin with.

Comment: @Gnemlock Thing is, we'd have to ask that about [tag:circle] too. That was meant to be a second question!

Comment: Perhaps we could discuss both tags/options in general; it seems moot to discuss merging tags if we than discuss removing them, and given the same arguments apply equally to [tag:circle], I think it appropriate to include it. I have also found [tag:hexagon] and [tag:triangles]. Alternatively, we have the tag [tag:shape] that may serve as a better core synonymn.

Comment: @Gnemlock I've created the question [here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2290/40264). I believe they're two different questions. Creating a tag synonym (rectangles -> rectangle) is a simple action, from what I understand, but the outcome of the other discussion can require more work to achieve.

Comment: Yes. Merging and linking (the latter especially) is pretty straightforward, usually (and in this case doesn't seem worth much thought). Blacklisting tags is something I'd like to see more discussion on, or at least let the idea percolate for a few days, so it'd be good to have a separate discussion about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged [rectangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangles) into [rectangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) and made the appropriate synonym link.