# List of hex grid questions missing the 'hexagon' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm aware of this question in Meta: [Do we need tags for 'rectangle', 'circle', 'triangle', 'hexagon' and 'shape'?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape), and as a hex grid nut I think the 'hexagon' tag is a special case.

Having said that, I've found a list of questions related to hexagons (as in "hex grids") that are missing the 'hexagon' tag:

- [Tweaking Heightmap Generation For Hexagon Grids](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46086/tweaking-heightmap-generation-for-hexagon-grids)
- [Technical differences between square and hexagon for a grid?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76108/technical-differences-between-square-and-hexagon-for-a-grid)
- [How to orient a hexagonal tile on a geodesic sphere (Goldberg polyhedron)?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125201/how-to-orient-a-hexagonal-tile-on-a-geodesic-sphere-goldberg-polyhedron)
- [Hexagonal Game Board Modal?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83412/hexagonal-game-board-modal)
- [Showing range on hexagonal grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45063/showing-range-on-hexagonal-grid)
- [hexagonal grid Mouse over](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132952/hexagonal-grid-mouse-over)
- [LibGDX hexagonal tilemap getting adjacent tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111723/libgdx-hexagonal-tilemap-getting-adjacent-tiles)
- [Error in Finding Nearest Hexagonal Tile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99234/error-in-finding-nearest-hexagonal-tile)
- [Applying Textures to Hexagonal Tiles Seamlessly](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/applying-textures-to-hexagonal-tiles-seamlessly)
- [Elevation model for hexagonal game grids](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/elevation-model-for-hexagonal-game-grids)
- [Generating vertices for group of hexagons](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139493/generating-vertices-for-group-of-hexagons)
- [Find connected hex of same color](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46412/find-connected-hex-of-same-color)
- [Getting neighbors of hex tiles in 3D space](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84086/getting-neighbors-of-hex-tiles-in-3d-space)
- [How do I calculate hex coordinates from a ring and index?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131453/how-do-i-calculate-hex-coordinates-from-a-ring-and-index)
- [White dots artifacts when applying borders to hex tiled geometry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108700/white-dots-artifacts-when-applying-borders-to-hex-tiled-geometry)

**I'm not advocating for a massive serial retag**, as I know (and I've felt in other SE sites) how disruptive those massive retaggings are, but hopefully something slower and calmer could be done about it.

It would be nice to have 'hexagon', 'hexes' and 'hexgrid' search results under the same tag.

After all, this SE may be the best online resource about hex grids, bar the excellent guide at [Red Blob Games](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still feel that `hexagon` is too generic as a tag.

You have a point that all these questions are logically grouped under the concept of a hexagonal grid, however, so I don't immediately see anything wrong with a tag for [hexogonal-grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexogonal-grid) or similar (the *grid* being the important part).

Comment: I think 'hexagon' is not that bad as a compromise, because the calculations involving a hex grid are related to the specific geometric properties of the hexagon. 'hexagonal-grid' may be better though. Anyways, my post was more about (my perceived) need to add a 'hexagon' (or 'hexagonal-grid') tag to that list of questions. Maybe I should edit the question to clarify?

Comment: I think it's clear enough you're proposing adding a tag to those questions, and that's fine. I just don't think "hexagon" is a good candidate. The consensus is _already_ to blacklist it (so by adding it, you'd just be making more work to undo it and re-apply something more appropriate); in general we have far too many tags here that are pointlessly broad, making them useless. More concept- or technique-specific tags would be better, which is why I think some tag that includes the _grid_ aspect in the name would be better.

Comment: I just went ahead and made [tag:hexagonal-grid], so it should be possible to apply that to the appropriate questions in the list now.

Comment: I'm the first follower of [hexagonal-grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid), yes!

Comment: Shoud we remove the tag '[grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)' from questions tagged, or to be tagged, with '[hexagonal-grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid)'? An example: [Finding all hexagonal grid coordinates inside cover arc](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153127/finding-all-hexagonal-grid-coordinates-inside-cover-arc).

Comment: @Rodia In general, probably, as it's likely redundant (unless perhaps the question is _also_ about conventional grids as the `grid` tag covers).

Comment: All the [`hexagon`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagon) tagged questions have been moved to [`hexagonal-grid`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid) now, except for [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53830/how-to-determine-what-hexes-are-in-an-area-bounded-by-3-hexes) (edit was rejected by the poster), and two others that are not related to hex grids but genuinely to hexagons. May need a mod to edit these three questions and [burninate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2qer.png) `hexagon` once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, why can't you just do an edit a day (or whatever pace you feel would be non-disruptive) in which you apply the tag to a question from your hit list?

Granted, at the moment, your edits would need to get approval, but since you don't want a fast disruptive process, this shouldn't be a problem. I think it also grants you a bit of rep in the process. Seems win-win to me.

That being said, please make sure that hexs are a core part of the question when tagging. For instance, the last question ([White dots artifacts when applying borders to hex tiled geometry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108700/white-dots-artifacts-when-applying-borders-to-hex-tiled-geometry)) seems borderline - to me, that problem isn't about hexes per say, but issues with aliasing & diagonal lines. Since it is likely that others implementing hex grids might run into similar problems, it's probably okay to use the hex tag there, but hopefully you get the idea - a problem can utilize concept X without necessarily being about concept X.

Comment: That was my first idea, I edited today [Recognizing a hexagonal clickbox](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/recognizing-a-hexagonal-clickbox), but got a declined review, which I somehow understand. Good catch about last question, I had my doubts too, but I think ultimately it's hex grid related. I totally left outside the list questions mentioning hexagons as a trivial part, and questions about that Super Hexagon game :)