# Do we need a tag for quads?

Tags: discussion

Do we need a tag for [quads](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quads)?

As a follow up to [Do we need tags for 'rectangle', 'circle', 'triangle', 'hexagon' and 'shape'?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape), I was working through removal of the [rectangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) tag & I encountered some questions with the [quads](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quads) tag. To me it seems as meta as 'triangles' & 'polygon' both of which were flagged for removal.

Comment: I thought about raising the issue as a comment to the prior question. I decided against it since some people might care more about quads than the other tgas, but might not have noticed discussion about it if it was edited/commented into the old post about other shape tags. If it should be added to the other post, let me know.

Comment: All the [tag:quads] have been removed / replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, we don't need these tags. Posts that are tagged "quad" likely could be tagged something else more useful.